# Clip-path background-image

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: customshape]

Say i have the image above as a background of a div. can i clip everything in this div to the boundaries of the image?

I've searched and found as i think the most appropriate way with clip-path, but i have no idea how to define path of this  image. I have thought to make it with canvas, but the problem is element inside this div.

If anyone has some experience with this kind of staff i would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

[There are tools out there](http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101#section7) which can assist in creating clip-paths.

Here is a (rather crude) **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/kpvxvo8c/2/)** which I whipped up with [this tool](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/):

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background: tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(74.67px 148.00px,105.00px 244.24px,145.67px 315.35px,181.33px 324.47px,159.67px 295.47px,149.50px 218.74px,172.33px 155.00px,165.17px 82.00px,132.00px 10.00px,68.83px 72.00px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: i need this shape exactly which would be to hard using that tool assuming that this is not the only shape i will have to make. Something like shape-inside would be the best approach for complex shapes i think as @ckuijjer advised. But today it seems that it is still like a dream. because polyfill doesn't support shape-inside, and without polyfill no ie support for me is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible using [CSS Shapes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/). Unfortunately the browser support isn't there yet (it only works on Safari and Chrome) so you might need a [polyfill](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/05/12/css-shapes-polyfill/).

I've added a small code snippet that shows how it can work using your image. Note that due to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues I've had to inline the image using a data-uri.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  color: #333;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.shape {
  float: left;
  shape-margin: 10px;
  shape-outside: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b0qi.png" class="shape" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet rump kielbasa kevin tail. Chuck sirloin bresaola, swine andouille ham hock meatloaf pancetta jerky meatball corned beef shankle ribeye chicken beef ribs. Tenderloin pastrami sirloin corned beef, short ribs pancetta shoulder chicken
      porchetta ham ball tip kielbasa. Tri-tip porchetta meatloaf ground round sausage, pork loin shankle chicken. Turkey beef ribs capicola andouille pancetta. Beef ribs kevin venison ham ham hock sirloin, rump fatback shankle pork chop pastrami tri-tip
      andouille.
    </p>
    <p>
      Doner chicken bacon short ribs venison salami andouille biltong pig. Turkey bacon andouille shoulder kevin. Ham hock rump bacon corned beef, t-bone kevin tongue jerky meatball ground round ribeye tri-tip. Turkey swine bresaola prosciutto beef, porchetta
      short ribs drumstick. Meatball pork ribeye ham hock venison turducken.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, i made a research on that thing, i can't get to work the shape-inside thing which i need even on chrome.It will be a nice solution i think but after 1 year or so :(

Comment: I've added an example that shows how you can use it in Chrome, didn't add the polyfill though. I think you didn't get it to work due to the image being served from another domain (you can check if there's an error in Chrome's DevTools).

Comment: I think my solution is exactly the opposite of what you want (you want content within the image). Perhaps try to see if you can use `clip-path` with a `<svg>` that contains an `<image>`

Comment: shape-outside works, shape-inside doesn't, i gave up on idea of making it without images even though i hate it so much...thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unserstand how to use clip-path you can learn here:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

and here: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

**Or use a generator here -**

http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case and functionality inside the div, you could also use mask on the parent div. If I understood you correctly, it works as you want but it doesn't actually clip the content as the clip-path would.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask